# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: NoSuchSessionError: invalid session id selenium webdriver

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, integration-testing

I am running integration tests using Selenium.
I have `"selenium-webdriver": "^4.0.0-alpha.1" and "chromedriver": "^2.42.0"`. Tests are passing but still getting `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: NoSuchSessionError: invalid session id`. I have figured out that it's happening while calling `this.driver.quit()` in After hook. I have checked driver's sessionId is same in the beginning and while running *After* hook. This is the code:

**hooks.js**

```
function openWindow(driver) {
  var verifyItsYouBtnXpath = "*//span[text()='Continue']/ancestor::div[@role='button']";
  switchTab(driver).then(function() {
    driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath(verifyItsYouBtnXpath))).then((verifyElement) => {
      verifyElement.click();
        navigateToEmail(driver).then(() => {
          driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath("//td[*//span[text()='Integration Test Mail Thread']]")))
            .then((element) => {
              driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(element)).click()
                .then(() => {
                  driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@aria-label='Thumbs Up!!']")))
                    .then(element => {
                      driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(element)).click();
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
  });
}
```

**spec.js**

```
'use strict';

var {Then, When} = require('cucumber');
var {By, until} = require('selenium-webdriver');
var assert = require('assert');

When(/^Reaction Add-on is open$/, function (next) {
  next();
});

Then(/^User should get author name and first few words from message body$/, function (next) {
  var parentDivXpath = "//div[@jsaction='click:h5M12e; clickmod:h5M12e;']/preceding-sibling::div";
  var spanXpath = parentDivXpath + "/div/span[1]";
  this.driver.wait(
    until.elementsLocated(By.xpath(spanXpath))
  ).then(elements => {
    this.driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(elements[0]))
      .then(element => {
        element.getText().then(text => {
          assert.equal(text, "Hello,  Please like...");
        });
      });

    this.driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(elements[1]))
      .then(element => {
        element.getText().then(text => {
          assert.equal(text, "Done. I liked it....");
          assert.equal(elements.length, 2);
        });
      });
  });

  this.driver.wait(
    until.elementsLocated(By.xpath(spanXpath + "/following-sibling::span"))
  ).then(elements => {
    this.driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(elements[0]))
      .then(element => {
        element.getText().then(text => {
          assert.equal(text.includes("J King"), true);
        });
      });

    this.driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(elements[1]))
      .then(element => {
        element.getText().then(text => {
          assert.equal(text.includes("PM Meg"), true);
          assert.equal(elements.length, 2);
          next();
        });
      });
  });
});
```

And this is the error, I am getting. But tests are passing.

```
1 scenario (1 passed)
2 steps (2 passed)
0m56.079s
(node:3178) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: NoSuchSessionError: invalid session id
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591059 (a3d9684d10d61aa0c45f6723b327283be1ebaad8),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.6 x86_64)
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/Users/jaiprak/workspace/reaction-app/spec/integration_tests/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:585:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/Users/jaiprak/workspace/reaction-app/spec/integration_tests/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:533:13)
    at Executor.execute (/Users/jaiprak/workspace/reaction-app/spec/integration_tests/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:468:26)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:118:7)
(node:3178) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 3)
```

Comment: On reason Promises have been added was to prevent callback hells. So without looking in detail on `openWindow` or your test cases you can already assume that you use Promises the wrong way. Taking a closer look you can see that you always start a detached Promise chain that you don’t return and for which you also don’t add a `catch` so most of your Promise chains are candidates to throw an UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Comment: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/6824 Hope it may helpful for others.

Answer (score 5):

Use timeout to delay the process, and it would work!

```
setTimeout(() => {
        driver.quit();
    }, 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

For me it was solved when I added:

```
"--remote-debugging-port=" + nextPort
```

I use varibale nextPort to use many drivers
Full Code:

```
 let options = new chrome.Options()
 nextPort++
 console.log('nextPort = ' + nextPort)
 options.addArguments(["--no-sandbox",
                       "--disable-gpu",
                       "--headless",
                       "--remote-debugging-port=" + nextPort])
 let driver = new webdriver.Builder()
     .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome())
     .setChromeOptions(options)
     .build()
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me: simply remove the reference from your driver after quitting since the GC might not have removed it yet and you will end up reusing same driver, but with an invalid session:

```
function quit(){
    driver.quit();
    driver = null;
}
```